# Why does C++ node api for electron not allow for initialization of arraybuffers using external data?

Tags: c++, node.js, electron

I was recently developing a NodeJs module for electron using C++ and the Node addon C++ API.

I wanted to create an ArrayBuffer object containing the data of an image I read using c++ iostream functions like ifstream::read(). I allocated the buffer holding the image data using the "new char[]" operator and then tried to pass the pointer to the function Napi::ArrayBuffer::New(napi_env, void*, size_t) but when I try to run the electron application I get the following error:

```
[45256:1208/161314.044:ERROR:node_bindings.cc(149)] Fatal error in V8: v8_ArrayBuffer_NewBackingStore When the V8 Sandbox is enabled, ArrayBuffer backing stores must be allocated inside the sandbox address space. Please use an appropriate ArrayBuffer::Allocator to allocate these buffers, or disable the sandbox.
[45256:1208/161314.074:ERROR:crashpad_client_win.cc(844)] not connected
```

I have no idea of what it means nor did I find anything on the internet about fixing this issue.

Here is the code:

addon.cc:

```cpp
Napi::ArrayBuffer loadImage(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info) {
  std::ifstream image("img.jpg");
  Napi::ArrayBuffer imageBuffer;
  int bufferSize;

  image.seekg(0, image.end);
  bufferSize = image.tellg();
  image.seekg(0, image.beg);

  char *data = new char[bufferSize];

  image.read(data, bufferSize);

  imageBuffer = Napi::ArrayBuffer::New(info.Env(), (void*)data, bufferSize);

  return imageBuffer;
}
```

addon.js:

```js
const testAddon = require('./build/Release/testaddon.node')
const electron = require("electron")
const path = require('path')
const { ipcMain, BrowserWindow, app } = require('electron');

const createWindow = () => {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600, webPreferences: {
        preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }, contextIsolation: true})

    win.loadFile("test.html")
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {createWindow()})

var eddu = testAddon.loadImage();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Electron broke this in 21 as you noticed, there has been some discussion with them at https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/35801.

But the ultimate answer is that you can't do `Napi::ArrayBuffer::New()` with an existing pointer anymore in Electron. As you are already doing a copy into `data` you could instead do:

```
imageBuffer = Napi::ArrayBuffer::New(info.Env(), bufferSize);

image.read(imageBuffer.Data(), bufferSize);
```

Or in other cases where a copy is not being done then `Napi::ArrayBuffer::Copy()` could be used instead, or the upcoming `Napi::ArrayBuffer::NewOrCopy()` method.

Ref: https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/blob/main/doc/array_buffer.md